# No iPad simulator in Xcode 3.2 beta 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I installed Xcode 3.2 beta 5 and I could not find iPad Simulator. Where do I find it?

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for the program `iPhone Simulator`.

> If not, you can test your website in Safari on iPad using the iPhone Simulator (Hardware -> Device -> iPad).

Above is from [Technical Note TN2262](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html)

If you can't find it via searchlight, than try looking in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator

Comment: Based on cde's comment to your post, My post is not a violation of the NDA, nor is OP's question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the NDA bits; several flags, but I'm satisfied that this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Go to spotlight and search iOS Simulator. You run that and up pops an iPhone simulator, go to Hardware > Device and change it to an iPad

The iOS Simulator is in Mac HD > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneSimulator.platform > Developer > Applications > (here)

Nicely squirrelled away

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an iPad project and ask to launch it in the simulator.

When running, go to the dock, right click on the icon and select "options".

In the "Options" menu is "Reveal in Finder", which will show you where the simulator currently lives.

Also be aware that the iPhone and iPad simulator are the same application, in the menu for the iPhone Simulator (the actual name of the app) you can select which device you want to simulate (though XCode will automatically switch this for you when you run in debug).

Comment: Why the downvotes? Not the best answer on SO but is not that bad, is it?

Comment: Well it was sparse before, I filled it out a bit.  Thanks for the upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

After you install the SDK successfully, Run Xcode and create a new project. Select iPad for product.
When you create an iPhone project for iPhone OS 3.2, you will see that every time you Build and Run  it, it appears in the iPad simulator instead of the iPhone simulato

---

There is not much too see when you run the simulator without a project

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this pertains,

From Xcode release notes found under the download selection:

Known Issues in Xcode 5 developer preview
Simulator
There is no iPad simulator support in this seed.

Comment: Question was asked 2 years ago. I doubt he was referring to XCode 5